# Java - get command line arguments, OUTSIDE of main?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

Is there a way in java to get the command line arguments that were passed to a program *outside* of the `main` function?

I'm writing some code that's part of a larger application I don't control, and I'd like to know what the command line args were, without modifying the `main` function.

Note: I've seen [how to get the JVM arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/716153/26510), and [how to get the arguments in main](https://stackoverflow.com/q/716153/26510), but would like to get it in other parts of our app, without having them saved in the `main` function, which I don't control.

Comment: Well, if you know the names of those arguments (and want to use names in the first place) you could pass them as system properties instead. Thus you'd be able to access them via `System.getProperty(name)`.

Comment: Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541627/how-do-i-get-the-commandline-that-started-the-process

Comment: You could try the property "sun.java.command". It gives you access to the full command that was used to execute the jar (I'll check the docs, wether this is portable between JVM-implementations).

Comment: @Paul - i just tried it, and for me on my mac at least, that totally worked...  Thanks for suggesting it ! and the line to get it is pretty much `System.getProperty("sun.java.command");`

Comment: @BradParks update: as the prefix "sun" suggests, this property is most likely a oracle-jre specific system property. I haven't found any resources to verify this, so please handle with care.

Comment: @Paul - not sure what you mean by "as the prefix" ?

Comment: This also works on windows 7 with the oracle jre.

Comment: @Paul - you should totally add this as an answer to the question this was a duplicate of, namely [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5061367/26510). And good point about the "sun." prefix bit - i get ya now!

Answer (score 13):

When starting the jvm this way: `java -DmyArgument=myValue -jar your.jar` you can get the value of myArgument everywhere in your java code with `String myArg = System.getProperty("myArgument");`

Comment: Thanks... that's helpful, but the args that I'm looking for aren't passed as `-D` style arguments....